# How do you set the row height in Semantic UI?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

How do you set the row height in Semantic UI given this,

```
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="row">
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? And you'e missing a quotation mark at the `.row` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'row' class set height.

eg.

```
.row {
height: 100px;
}
```